# Writing an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Can anybody please tell me how i would programatically create the following as a multi-dimensional array in C#.

```
data: [
    { Beacon: '1', Interactions: 136 },
    { Beacon: '3G', Interactions: 1037 },
    { Beacon: '3GS', Interactions: 275 },
    { Beacon: '4', Interactions: 380 },
    { Beacon: '4S', Interactions: 655 },
    { Beacon: '5', Interactions: 1571 }
       ],
```

I'm guessing i start with something like:

```
string[,] myBeaconArray = new string[numberOfBeacons, 1];
```

But then how do i build each entry? Baring in mind that the digits in single quotes (i.e the 1, 3G, 3GS etc) and the numbers (i.e 136, 1037 etc) are also variables.

I assumed it would be something like

```
myBeaconArray[positionNumber, "Beacon: '" + variable1 + "', Interactions: " + variable2 ];
```

But this is clearly not right. This is my first look into multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: You only have a single dimension's worth of data, not two dimension's worth of data.  You should have a single dimensional data structure.

Comment: string[][] myBeaconArray = new string[numberOfBeacons][numberOfInteractions];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a multidimensional array, at least not from your example.  Try this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Beacon { get; set; }
    public int Interactions { get; set; }
}
```

To create a list, use this:

```
List<RootObject> myBeaconArray=new List<RootObject>()
{
    new RootObject{ Beacon= "1", Interactions= 136 },
    new RootObject{ Beacon= "3G", Interactions= 1037 }
};
```

To create a fixed length array, use this:

```
var myBeaconArray= new RootObject[]
{
    new RootObject{ Beacon= "1", Interactions= 136 },
    new RootObject{ Beacon= "3G", Interactions= 1037 }
};
```

If you don't need to pass the object around, you can use anonymous obejcts like this:

```
var myBeaconArray= new []
{
    new { Beacon= "1", Interactions= 136 },
    new { Beacon= "3G", Interactions= 1037 }
};
```

Comment: As a shortcut, copy a sample of your json into something like this: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3):

You should just create a type with two properties: `Beacon` and `Interactions`, then have an array of that type instead of a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

When you have class :

```
    public class MobileStatistics
    {
        public string Beacon { get; set; }
        public int Interactions { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you could write :

```
        var items = new List<MobileStatistics>
        {
            new MobileStatistics{ Beacon= "1", Interactions= 136 },
            new MobileStatistics{ Beacon= "3G", Interactions= 1037 }
            //...
        };
```

To use it *(using lambas)

```
        foreach (var message in items.Select(o => string.Format("Beacon: '{0}', Interactions: {1}", o.Beacon, o.Interactions)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
alert(items[0][0]);
```